# Connect To Terminal Server

Tags: javascript, php, python, terminal, putty

I have a site built in Javascript/PHP.

I have a terminal server that I can connect to using puTTy.
What I would like is to display the terminal server on the website. 
I want to be able to send data to the terminal server through the code and display the response in the terminal screen.

I am not sure what could help me accomplish this. Are there any Javascript, PHP, Python plugins for this type of thing? I was able to play around with one PHP plugin but it only allowed me to send a command and get a response back. I would like to be able to actually see the terminal session as I would in puTTy.

Comment: You realize that you'd have to log into the terminal server, execute a command, then log out again, for **EVERY** request the client makes? HTTP doesn't work like telnet/ssh.

Comment: That is fine and would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java applet for this.

http://weavervsworld.com/ssh/ssh.php